# How to embed a video in my HTML5-App?

Tags: mysql, html, video

I have been trying to upload the video to Onedrive and use the HTML5 Video tag, but there was just an error message. The main problem is, that I don't know how to do it with an online video, as it should also be available on a smartphone. That's why I can't just specify a local path, I need some way to use the same video on different platforms. I do also have a MySQL Database where all the other data for my app is stored, but I could not figure out how to insert a video into the database.

What's the best way to do that and where should I store my video?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide video to the user in some way. Either he will download them with the application, or he will have to download them from the internet (`<video>`). You can also embed the video using `<iframe>`.

To use the video tag you need to know the direct address of the video file (local or on a web server) This can not be a page where you have "Click to download". So, for example, you put a video file on your web server or provide a direct link, for example on a dropbox.

The recommended option is to send a video file to the streaming video server (YT, google drive, openload) and embed it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!